# Cordova: In app browser issue on iPhone - black bar grows

Tags: iphone, cordova

I am working on iPhone app using Phonegap.
I have used in app browser functionality in my app. Though it works fine but gives following issue.

I have used.

```
 window.open('http://www.yahoo.com','_blank','location=yes');
```

**Issue is:**

when I click to open webpage in app browser with **Done** at the bottom, it opens the webpage successfully, when I click Done and go back a **black bar appears** at the bottom of the screen that **grows** each time I use in app browser.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Share some details; Cordova version, iOS version and did you use standard InAppbrowser plugin or custom. nice to have a snapshot as well

Comment: Try window.open('http://www.yahoo.com','_blank'); without adding "location=yes" and see the difference.

Comment: I tried without adding location. No success. I am getting same issue.

Comment: Can you please share snapshot of the screen having issue?

Comment: I am new user and its not allowing me to post images :(

Comment: oh okay, then post image somewhere on cloud and provide its link, like post on dropbox etc. Because it will help visualize the issue

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9zC4fZ7clfrWGticWt4NlVCOVE/view?usp=sharing